# Can I use elementary block matrix transformation to solve this rank equation problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$(1)$ Let's suppose $A,B$ are $n-$order matrix, satisfying $AB=BA=O$, $r(A)=r(A^2)$, prove that$$r(A+B)=r(A)+r(B)$$

To prove this, I construct the following block matrix $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    A & O \\
    O & B \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then I want to use the fact that "addition transformation does not change the rank of the matrix", I hope after this type transformation, the block matrix look like $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    A+B & O \\
    O & O \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

The difficulty is that I can't use $r(A)=r(A^2)$ properly. So can someone give me some hints ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

Let $f$ be a linear operator of a linear space $L$ with matrix $A$
in some basis of $L$.

If $M=f(L)$, then $f(M)=M$. (Use here the equality $r(A)=r(A^2)$.)

It follows that the matrix $A$ is conjugate to a block matrix of the form

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  A_{11} & A_{12} \\
  0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $|A_{11}|\neq0$. (What are the dimensions of the blocks?)

Let
$$
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
  B_{11} & B_{12} \\
  B_{21} & B_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $AB=BA=0$, then $B_{11}=0$, $B_{12}=0$, $B_{21}=0$.

Now you can easily prove your equality.

Comment: The first two sentences of your proof might be confusing if OP is not used to discussing linear operators rather than matrices or does not understand that $f(L)$ refers to the image/range of $f$.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann, I agree with you, it is possible not to involve the concept of a linear operator, although I like this approach.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great method. But I hope we may not introduce any concept of linear operaotr at all. I am searching for a method that only uses elementary block matrix.